# How to connect my Rails Application localhost with replica-set postgres GPC

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

Is it possible to establish connection from my localhost app to a replica-set postgres kubernetes? or what solution I need to do for having a mirror of my production database?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide more details regarding your cluster conf and app. What have you tried already?

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a so-called PostgreSQL [Kubernetes operator](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/operator/) that will be responsible for building Kubernetes objects based on your requests.

You can have a look at [OperatorHub.io](https://operatorhub.io/), they have [some PostgreSQL operators](https://operatorhub.io/?keyword=postgres).

Maybe an easier solution is [KubeDB](https://kubedb.com) and [the KubeDB PostgreSQL implementation](https://kubedb.com/docs/v0.13.0-rc.0/guides/postgres/).

The operator will also create a [Kubernetes `Service`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) that will create a resolvable name linked to the [Kubernetes Pods](https://kubernetes.io/fr/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod/) of your PostgreSQL cluster. KubeDB doc explains [how to connect to the database in their documentation](https://kubedb.com/docs/v0.13.0-rc.0/guides/postgres/quickstart/quickstart/#connect-with-postgresql-database).

Now coming to your question :

> Is it possible to establish connection from my localhost app [...]

You can access the Kubernetes service from outside but you will have to create a Kubernetes Load Balancer. See [this blog article](https://gardener.cloud/050-tutorials/content/howto/service-access/) which explains it in details.